# How does state work in React sever side rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, state, server-rendering

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B65P35Qpdpc) and wanted to understand how the state for a component during the first page load is set to the component. Does the component already get built out with the state set on the server side and then get sent down to the client as HTML **OR** does the component get built out on the server side, get sent down to the client as HTML, and then run bundle.js to get the data?

Around the 8 minute mark in the video, the speaker talks about the window state needing to be set and be synced with the React state. What is that about? Why does there need to be state on the window if it's already set on the server side? Is it because it's not being set yet, and it's sent down separately from the server and the client component has to grab it off the window?

Comment: That's because the client-side react also needs the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using React with server rendering, we must also send the state of our app along in our response, so the client can use it as the initial state. This is important because, if we preload any data before generating the HTML, we want the client to also have access to this data. Otherwise, the markup generated on the client won't match the server markup, and the client would have to load the data again.

To send the data down to the client, we need to:

- create a fresh, new React store instance on every request;
     optionally dispatch some actions;
     pull the state out of store;
     and then pass the state along to the client.
     On the client side, a new React store will be created and initialized with the state provided from the server.

React's only job on the server side is to provide the initial state of our app.

Comment: when do you have to use window state?